# Sort Users in chat by most recent messages with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, chat

I need to **sort the array of users** inside my ReactJS chat application **by the new and more recent messages** send by the them, **updating at each new message**, like whatsApp or telegram, for instance.

Down are the simplified interface of the two diferent arrays: users and messages:

I'm using momentjs to handle with dates and the stored date format is a timestamp like this:
2021-03-26 00:17:50

```js
interface userProps {
  id: string;
  chat_id: string;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
}

interface messagesProps {
  id?: string;
  chat_id?: string;
  content?: string;
  send_by?: string;
  visualized?: boolean;
  created_at?: string;
}
```

All the messages are stored in the array and filtered by the chatID, witch both arrays have in common.

Does anyone knows what is the best solution for this challenge?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a code sandbox link that describes the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure how your chatrooms are involved but you could get users sorted by id with simple JS code like this:

```
const sortedUserIds = messages  // you array of messagesProps
  .sort() // you already know the correct way to sort your messages
  .map(m => m.send_by)
  .filter(m => m.send_by !== null)

const sortedUsers = [...new Set(sortedUserIds)].map(id => users.find(u => u.id === id))
```

Since you have react involved, you can trigger the code above based on `messages` array with react hooks:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);    

useEffect(() => {
  run the code above to get sorted users
  setUsers(your sorted users);
}, [messages])
  
return (
  <ul>
    {users.map(u => <li>{u.first_name}</li>)}
  </ul>
)
```